# create DataExtensions with IsSendable to true

Tags: marketing-cloud, fuel-sdk

I have been trying to create a DataExtention using the FuelSDK.

I followed this example

https://github.com/salesforce-marketingcloud/FuelSDK-PHP/blob/master/objsamples/sample-sendable-dataextension.php

My code snippet looks like:

```
$this->_dataExtensions->props = [
                'Name'                       => $content['name'],
                'Description'                => 'Sync - ' . date('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
                'CustomerKey'                => $content['key'],
                'IsSendable'                 => 'true',
                'SendableDataExtensionField' => ['Name' => 'EmailAddress', 'Value' => 'primaryEmail'],
            'SendableSubscriberField'    => ['Name' => 'Subscriber Key', 'Value' => 'CustomerKey'],
            ];
```

I have `SUBSCRIBER_KEY` on in the account. btw.

But the API response gives me

```
[results] => Array
        (
            [0] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [StatusCode] => Error
                    [StatusMessage] => The SendableCustomObjectField is invalid. 
                    [OrdinalID] => 0
                    [ErrorCode] => 310007
                    [NewID] => 0
                    [Object] => stdClass Object
```

I haven't found out a way to get around this error, or any working code samples in the FuelSdk repo or googling.

any ideas?

EDIT:

```
$this->_dataExtensions->columns = [
                [
                    'Name'         => 'customerKey',
                    'FieldType'    => 'Text',
                    'IsPrimaryKey' => 'true',
                    'MaxLength'    => '200',
                    'IsRequired'   => 'true'
                ],
                [
                    'Name'         => 'firstName',
                    'FieldType'    => 'Text',
                    'IsPrimaryKey' => 'no',
                    'MaxLength'    => '50',
                    'IsRequired'   => 'no'
                ],
                [
                    'Name'         => 'lastName',
                    'FieldType'    => 'Text',
                    'IsPrimaryKey' => 'no',
                    'MaxLength'    => '50',
                    'IsRequired'   => 'no'
                ],
                [
                    'Name'         => 'primaryEmail',
                    'FieldType'    => 'Text',
                    'IsPrimaryKey' => 'no',
                    'MaxLength'    => '254',
                    'IsRequired'   => 'no'
                ]
            ];
```

Comment: Does the DE have a field with the name 'EmailAddress'?

Comment: I also don't see where you are defining field names

Comment: i updated with my column definitions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From this help doc: '[Create a Data Extension](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/creating_a_data_extension_using_web_service_api.htm)'

the php example

```
$newde->SendableDataExtensionField = new Marketing Cloud_DataExtensionField();                           
$newde->SendableDataExtensionField->Name = 'EMAIL';
```

your `SendableDataExtensionField` should have a value of a field in your DE so for your example it should have the value of `customerKey`

I believe for the FuelSDK you need this line from the doc you included

`postDE->props["SendableCustomObjectField"]->props["Name"] = "customerKey";`

Answer (score 0):

In your example DE columns, you have a column named 'primaryEmail' and 'customerKey'. In your DE creation here:

```
 'SendableDataExtensionField' => ['Name' => 'EmailAddress', 'Value' => 'primaryEmail'],
        'SendableSubscriberField'    => ['Name' => 'Subscriber Key', 'Value' => 'CustomerKey'],
```

You have specified that name of the columns as 'EmailAddress' and 'Subscriber Key' which do not match you example DE column names.

Try modifying these to match the names of the columns you have specified in creation.  The values you have provided are there to allow specifying a default value for the column -- it looks as thought you are under the impression they are for specifying the column name.

Try:

```
 'SendableDataExtensionField' => ['Name' => 'primaryEmail'],
        'SendableSubscriberField'    => ['Name' => 'customerKey'],
        ]
```